# Ubuntu doesnt boot if selected in bootup option. Installed alongside Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 using live CD.Installation was successful. On restart, it used to boot with windows without providing choose option. Now, after creating a new entry using EasyBCD2.2, it provided me option of both Windows 8 and Ubuntu.Selecting windows 8 works normally.But On selecting Ubuntu, it doesnt boot up and says File:

```
\NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr   Status: 0xc000007b
```

Not able to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link with option at end below named "boot-repair" :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097815

have you tried it with

to enable efi instead of uefi in bios ?

Comment: i tried that boot-repair but i found the MBR options tab disabled as well as under 'other options' tab, "Repair windows boot files" was disabled. In other blog, which has similar issue of booting( http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/ ), i could not locate the path to add to Ubuntu install.